# JavaFX graphical glitch centering stage

Tags: javafx

When my JavaFX application changes the screen(stage) there is a visual glitch.
Looks like the window is set on the bottom left of the screen and after that it runs to the middle.
How to avoid this glitch?

```
 try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLChamado.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        // get stage
        Stage stage = (Stage) new Stage();
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(
            ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow() );

        stage.setTitle("My App");
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Not tested, but try calling `centerOnScreen` after setting the `Scene` (and maybe after calling `initOwner(...)`). The stage needs to know how big it is to be able to center itself.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: I stopped to use FXML and now my app is ok.